# Converting Age Ys/Ms to Decimal equivalent

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am trying to convert age written as years and month in to a decimal, where 12.06 (12yrs6mnths) would equal 12.5yrs).

I am a relative novice in formula writing and this is my best effort so far using =if to convert an age to it's decimal equivalent, but I'm getting a parse error.  Any help greatly appreciated.

```
=if((F4=4,4), if(F4=4.01,4.08),
if(F4=4.02,4.17),
if(F4=4.03,4.25),
if(F4=4.04,4.33),
if(F4=4.05,4.42),
If(F4=4.06,4.5),
if(F4=4.07,4.58),
  if(F4=4.08,4.67),
  if(F4=4.09,4.75),
  if(F4=4.1,4.83),
  if(F4=4.11,4.92),
  if(F4=5,5),
  if(F4=5.01,5.08),
  if(F4=5.02,5.17),
  if(F4=5.03,5.25),
  if(F4=5.04,5.33),
  if(F4=5.05,5.42),
  If(F4=5.06,5.5),
  if(F4=5.07,5.58),
  if(F4=5.08,5.67),
  if(F4=5.09,5.75),
  if(F4=5.1,5.83),
  if(F4=5.11,5.92),
  if(F4=6,6),
  if(F4=6.01,6.08),
  if(F4=6.02,6.17),
  if(F4=6.03,6.25),
  if(F4=6.04,6.33),
  if(F4=6.05,6.42),
  If(F4=6.06,6.5),
  if(F4=6.07,6.58),
  if(F4=6.08,6.67),
  if(F4=6.09,6.75),
  if(F4=6.1,6.83),
  if(F4=6.11,6.92),
  if(F4=7,7),
  if(F4=7.01,7.08),
  if(F4=7.02,7.17),
  if(F4=7.03,7.25),
  if(F4=7.04,7.33),
  if(F4=7.05,7.42),
  If(F4=7.06,7.5),
  if(F4=7.07,7.58),
  if(F4=7.08,7.67),
  if(F4=7.09,7.75),
  if(F4=7.1,7.83),
  if(F4=7.11,7.92),
  if(F4=8,8),
  if(F4=8.01,8.08),
  if(F4=8.02,8.17),
  if(F4=8.03,8.25),
  if(F4=8.04,8.33),
  if(F4=8.05,8.42),
  If(F4=8.06,8.5),
  if(F4=8.07,8.58),
  if(F4=8.08,8.67),
  if(F4=8.09,8.75),
  if(F4=8.1,8.83),
  if(F4=8.11,8.92),
  if(F4=9,9),
  if(F4=9.01,9.08),
  if(F4=9.02,9.17),
  if(F4=9.03,9.25),
  if(F4=9.04,9.33),
  if(F4=9.05,9.42),
  If(F4=9.06,9.5),
  if(F4=9.07,9.58),
  if(F4=9.08,9.67),
  if(F4=9.09,9.75),
  if(F4=9.1,9.83),
  if(F4=9.11,9.92),
  if(F4=10,10),
  if(F4=10.01,10.08),
  if(F4=10.02,10.17),
  if(F4=10.03,10.25),
  if(F4=10.04,10.33),
  if(F4=10.05,10.42),
  If(F4=10.06,10.5),
  if(F4=10.07,10.58),
  if(F4=10.08,10.67),
  if(F4=10.09,10.75),
  if(F4=10.1,10.83),
  if(F4=10.11,10.92),
  if(F4=11,11),
  if(F4=11.01,11.08),
  if(F4=11.02,11.17),
  if(F4=11.03,11.25),
  if(F4=11.04,11.33),
  if(F4=11.05,11.42),
  If(F4=11.06,11.5),
  if(F4=11.07,11.58),
  if(F4=11.08,11.67),
  if(F4=11.09,11.75),
  if(F4=11.1,11.83),
  if(F4=11.11,11.92),
  if(F4=12,12),
  if(F4=12.01,12.08),
  if(F4=12.02,12.17),
  if(F4=12.03,12.25),
  if(F4=12.04,12.33),
  if(F4=12.05,12.42),
  If(F4=12.06,12.5),
  if(F4=12.07,12.58),
  if(F4=12.08,12.67),
  if(F4=12.09,12.75),
  if(F4=12.1,12.83),
  if(F4=12.11,12.92),
  if(F4=13,13),
  if(F4=13.01,13.08),
  if(F4=13.02,13.17),
  if(F4=13.03,13.25),
  if(F4=13.04,13.33),
  if(F4=13.05,13.42),
  If(F4=13.06,13.5),
  if(F4=13.07,13.58),
  if(F4=13.08,13.67),
  if(F4=13.09,13.75),
  if(F4=13.1,13.83),
  if(F4=13.11,13.92))
```

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)?

Comment: Thank you for the welcome.  I would argue that it isn't an XY problem.  I have a problem, I have stipulated the issue that I am trying to solve, trying to give as much pertinent information as I could.  I have shown how I have tried to solve it, but in asking the problem, acknowledge that this isn't how to do it.  I very much appreciate the response and that you were able to solve it in one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`=regexextract(trim(F4), "^\d+") + regexextract(trim(F4), "\d+$") / 12`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it is really appreciated.  Would I do this for each step? Or would this massively simplify the whole formula?

Comment: If cell `F4` contains `12.06`, the formula will give `12.5`, i.e., your expected result.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again - could I ask what the formula would be to reverse the formula, ie: from decimal to yr/month?

Comment: That is a different question. Please post it as a new question, and describe the _problem_ rather than describing your _attempted solution_.

Answer (score 0):

I read the solution offered by doubleunary. It does have one flaw, which is that the formula as written will incorrectly convert integer-only numbers (e.g., 4, 5, 6, etc.).

The following modification will work in all cases:

`=regexextract(trim(F4), "^\d+") + iferror(regexextract(trim(F4), ".(\d+)$") / 12)`

In order to keep the structure of x.xx *and* convert correctly back and forth, you will need to apply formatting (**Format > Number > Number)** to the applicable range(s) or wrap such a formula in ROUND( ,2), i.e.:

`=round((regexextract(trim(F4), "^\d+") + iferror(regexextract(trim(F4), ".(\d+)$") / 12)),2)`

Any reverse calculation will need the same treatment.

I will also note to the original poster that such a formula could be adapted to work on an entire range (e.g., column?) of numbers if such were required and we knew the format of the sheet. If you only need one number converted, this formula setup is fine; but if you find you are dragging the formula around, it is probably not necessary. In the latter case, consider sharing a link to a copy of your spreadsheet with any confidential information (e.g., student names, etc.) sanitized and show where you want the results to go.

Comment: Many thanks, Erik!