# How to convert decimal years.months into a number that looks like years.months in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I [previously asked](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/155559/269219) how to convert age represented as year.months: 12.06 in to decimal equivalent, in this case 12.5. Fo the second step of my problem, I would like to be able to convert this decimal back to the year.month format after I have been able to run a calculation.

The original answer that came back and worked perfectly for step 1 was:

`=regexextract(trim(F4), "^\d+") + regexextract(trim(F4), "\d+$") / 12`

but as I am unfamiliar with `regextract()` I was unable to reverse engineer the formula to go from decimal to year.month.

Comment: It remains unclear why you are doing these cumbersome conversions. It would seem much simpler to just use regular date values and functions like `year()` and `month()`. See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219) for an explanation of how date and time values work in spreadsheets.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out - The year.month data is a representation of student reading age generated by an online system, rather than chronological age.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us assume you have the value `12.06` in cell `F4`, and this formula in cell `G4`:

`=regexextract(trim(F4), "^\d+") + regexextract(trim(F4), "\d+$") / 12`

The easiest way to get back to the value in cell `F4` is as follows:

`=F4`

...while here is the unnecessarily convoluted way to back to the value in cell `F4`, using the result in cell `G4` for no apparent reason:

`=int(G4) + 0.12 * (G4 - int(G4))`

Comment: Thank you @doubleunary.  Step 1 converts the y.m data to a decimal so I can perform a calculation.  Step 2 is to convert the product of the step 1 calculation back in to a y.m representation.  I know it seems unnecessarily convoluted, but this was exactly what was required.  Many thanks for your patience and assistance.

Comment: I have up voted and accepted, but as my reputation is low, it tells me I am unable to cast a vote but my feedback has been recorded.